# Redis Cluster Behind a Loadbalancer?

Tags: redis

I am having a question about the redis cluster architecture.

I'm setting up a Redis Cluster and I'm following the basic recommendation:
3 Master
3 Slaves

Is there any way to configure this cluster behind a loadbalancer like Amazon LB, HAProxy, Nginx ...?

I'm not understanding how I should address my writing. I suppose I should write only on the 3 master servers but I do not know how to configure my application or loadbalancer to forward "write" only to the 3 master servers.

My use will only be for a read/write of type Key=Value.

Refer: 
Redis cluster tutorial
https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Thank you,

Comment: Hi, I would like to know is there any specific reason to use the load balancer before Redis cluster. in my opinion Redis cluster itself able to distribute the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was facing the same issue a lil while ago when I found [this article](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-setup-HAProxy-and-Redis-Sentinel-for-automatic-failover-between-Redis-Master-and-Slave-servers) and followed all the steps related to Haproxy.

After that i was able to use redis-cluster with my **`haproxy-ip:haproxy-port`**

If you are using *debian* or *ubuntu* systems you can download it from [here](https://haproxy.debian.net/) :)

Cheers

Comment: Hello Ayushi, I'm using Netflix Dynomite for multiple read/writes and master/master architecture.